# applying function to vector wise to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4 x 2 matrix, i.e. a numpy vector(of length 4) of numpy vectors of length two. For example a = [[1,1],[1,2],[3,5],[8,3]]
I want to subtract the vector  b = [3,6] from each row.
I tried to do the following:

```
np.vectorize(lamda x: x-b)(a)
```

but i get the error ValueError:

```
setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can somebody explain me why and how to do this the right way?

Comment: Try : `a - b[:,None]`, where `a` and `b` are the array and vector.

Comment: For your case, simply `a-b` should work following the rules of broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

first convert them to numpy array and then subtract b from a:

```
a = np.asarray(a)
b = np.asarray(b)
print a - b
```